# What is the specific term for the callback that you pass to the javascript Promise constructor?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

The ES6 Promise takes a callback as argument:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
```

Is there a term for these *callback-you-pass-to-create-a-promise*'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ECMAScript 6 Language Specification calls it an *executor*. See section [24.4.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise-executor).

Comment: Thanks, that is very definitive.

Comment: [We used to call](https://github.com/promises-aplus/constructor-spec/issues/18) them "resolvers".

Answer (score 0):

They are usually referred to as "targets".

Answer (score 0):

I would just call them "callbacks"

But if you want to be specific then success and error callbacks.